# Getting the signed in status as true on load

Tags: javascript, html, google-signin

I would like to know if I am signed in when the page has been loaded.

The following code returns `false`:

```
function init() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
}
```

The value of my element (`<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>`) is "Sign in" but after the page has loaded completely, it turns to "Signed in". I think that might be why I get `false`.

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>OAuth</title>
   <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="420430821131-c5t2p83bvsca290e6iu4h1ih5t1bpg45.apps.googleusercontent.com">
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="comment-area">
      <p class="login-info">To write a message, please login with Google.</p>
      <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
   </div>
   <script src="../assets/js/oauth.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();` outside of the `init()` function but it returns:

> oauth.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

How can I get `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to check after the page is completely loaded

```
window.onload = function() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function () {
    log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
  });
};
```